# Getting a null value in my input file type field

Tags: php, jquery, smarty3

I downloaded a web application and i found out that it is created using Smarty Template Engine. I want to add an avatar field when creating new company so i added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `<input type="file" name="avatar">` to the existing `<form>` and i also added `avatar` to my `companies table` in my database.  Here is the HTML code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="ib_modal_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-4 control-label" for="company_name">{$_L['Company Name']}<small class="red">*</small></label>
            <div class="col-lg-8"><input type="text" id="company_name" name="company_name" class="form-control" value="{$val['company_name']}"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-4 control-label" for="avatar">{$_L['Avatar']}</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8"><input type="file" name="avatar"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-4 control-label" for="email">{$_L['Email']}</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8"><input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{$val['email']}"> </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">{$_L['Cancel']}</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary modal_submit" type="submit" id="modal_submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> {$_L['Save']}</button>
</div>
```

I found out that the form goes to this javascript code when clicking the Save Button:

```
$modal.on('click', '.modal_submit', function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            $.post( _url + "contacts/add_company_post/", $("#ib_modal_form").serialize())
                .done(function( data ) {

                    if ($.isNumeric(data)) {

                        location.reload();

                    }

                    else {
                        $modal.modal('loading');
                        toastr.error(data);
                    }

                });

        });
```

Here is the code in the Controller:

```
case 'add_company_post':

    $data = ib_posted_data();
        $company = Model::factory('Models_Company')->create();
    $company->company_name = $data['company_name'];
    $company->url = $data['url'];
    $company->email = $data['email'];
    $company->phone = $data['phone'];
    $company->logo_url = $data['logo_url'];
    $company->avatar = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];

    $company->save();
    break;
```

The problem is that it does not recognize `$_FILES['avatar']['name'];` in the Controller  Whenever i add a new company, i get a NULL value in my database. I cant seem to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: check if `$_FILES` has value

Comment: `$_FILES['avatar']['name'];` works when i removed the javascript and directed the form by adding `action=" "` to it, since i just downloaded the application, i am not sure if removing the javascript code is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

From

```
$("#ib_modal_form").serialize()
```

To

```
new FormData($("#ib_modal_form")[0])
```

You should use FormData for uploading files using ajax. $(form).serialize() will give you just key and value.

Can you change your ajax call below way

```
$modal.on('click', '.modal_submit', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData($("#ib_modal_form")[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: _url + "contacts/add_company_post/",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if ($.isNumeric(data)) {

                    location.reload();

                }

                else {
                    $modal.modal('loading');
                    toastr.error(data);
                }
            },
        });

    });
```

Comment: Is that a jQuery specific solution? If so, will the OP need a specific jQuery version for this to work?

Comment: No there is no need of specific jquery version. $.post is jquery ajax post method it will work with any jquery version

Comment: is it ok to remove the JavaScript code and direct the form by adding `action=" "` to it? because i downloaded this application and i don't know if removing the JavaScript is a good idea. and what does the javascript do?

Comment: I see now. They could achieve this with `new FormData(document.getElementById.("ib_modal_form")` the same way. Nice.

Comment: It's upon your requirement. If you add action=" " and want to direct then you have to add submit button insideyour form and after form submission your page will reload and your js wont be called

Comment: when i change `$("#ib_modal_form").serialize()` to  `new FormData($("#ib_modal_form")[0])` i am getting this error on my console -  `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: @RonaldTorres i updated my answer can you check other way of calling ajax